# Loading changed class files to JVM using JNI

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

I am developing a Java IDE for Windows, as a learning project, and I have hit a barrier which I cannot find a way around.

I am using JNI to invoke the JVM and use javac to compile my code.

The JVM starts properly and when a java code is compiled for the first time the JVM takes them from the classpaths and correctly runs it.

But after I edit a java file, compile (uses a script to compile) and run the code, the JVM still loads the class file which got compiled during the first run. I have to stop the whole process and start the JVM again in order to take the changes.

I know there should be a way this is handled in IDEs like Eclipse or IntelliJ. But I couldn't seem to find how. I would really appreciate if someone can help me out.

The code I used to find and load classfiles is below.

```
bool load(const char* classFile)
{   
    JNIEnv* env;
    bool isAttached = Interpreter::getEnv(&env);
    auto javacls = env->FindClass(classFile);
    if (javacls == nullptr)
    {
        getLogger().error("ERR: Loading class file %s failed", classFile);
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
        return false;
    }
    auto classInstance = getObject(javacls);

    if (classInstance == nullptr)
    {
        getLogger().error("ERR: Invalid Object");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Changing code on-the-fly only works through an Instrumentation API, in case of native code, [JVMTI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#RetransformClasses.classes); that’s what debuggers use.

Comment: @Holger Thank you. I will look in to the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used for this was creating a sub-process that invokes JVM, then does everything that needs to be done and exits. This way each time the sub-process is invoked it creates a new JVM, hence loading the changed class files each time.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the code under test under a separate `ClassLoader`, and use a new one after each compilation, maybe even for each run.

You don't need any JNI.

Comment: Yes I know I can write this purely using Java. But I need to do this using JNI as I am trying to learn it. Also as I know Eclipse uses JNI to invoke a JVM right?

Comment: You *can't* do this via JNI, unless you go to the extreme length of creating and invoking a new `ClassLoader` via JNI. It's pointless. Find something else that does need JNI. Eclipse is already running in a JVM, so either it starts a new JVM *process* per run, essentially via `java.lang.Process`, or else it does what I've recommended above. Java has never supported multiple JVMs within a single process.

Comment: If I call loadClass method in ClassLoader using JNI would it load the latest classfile or would it take the one which is already loaded? Because if it can load the new class file it would solve my question.

Comment: You need a new classloader to load the new classfile. I've already stated that.